# Slow MySQL Query With Dependent Subquery (Checking if Client's 1st Case)

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, subquery

I have an SQL query (MySQL) I use for gathering the details of new cases (jobs) that are generated from clients who are referred by a particular referring company. Importantly, we need to only select those where it is the client's first case, otherwise repeat clients would register as being referred over and over and that's not what we're trying to get. In our system we have clients and cases tables and they are connected by an m:n table (in practice is just 1:n), so that is used to relate cases with their corresponding clients.

The requirement for only returning values where it is the client's first case is giving me trouble. To do that, I have a subquery in the WHERE clause that checks if a particular case is the client's first by looking for any other cases by that client. This gives correct output, but makes the query run quite slowly and I'm not sure what to do about it, which is why I turn to you StackOverflow to find a better way. If I remove that subquery, it runs instantly. I have tried altering the subquery to check COUNT(*) = 0 instead of NOT EXISTS. I have also altered it to check for any lesser case_ids instead of checking for earlier case created dates. I've tried tweaking other things and in each case I got similar slow results (~45 seconds vs instant). I don't know how to rework things to make it not a dependent subquery. One alternative I've thought of is to just put in a simple field into the cases table denoting if it's the client's first case or not, but that brings up other problems and isn't what I want to do if possible.

Note: I can't rule out clients if they have more than one case, since I need the first one. I can't

I was going to simplify the query for you but then I realized that I would also have to figure out how that would come out in the EXPLAIN results to modify those also so I didn't. We have a clients and a contacts table and contacts are children of clients, and the contacts are the ones with cases and have the referred by value saved, but we're going by clients for purposes of determining if they had a case previously.

Try 1:

```
SELECT c2.case_id AS Case_ID, [other stuff]
FROM client_contact_cases c1 LEFT JOIN cases c2 ON (c1.case_id = c2.case_id)
LEFT JOIN client_contact c3 ON (c1.client_contact_id = c3.client_contact_id) 
WHERE c2.case_created_date > '2013-05-01 00:00:00' AND c2.case_created_date < '2013-10-31 23:59:59' 
AND c3.refer_by = 'Referring Partner #1' 
AND NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT c2_a.case_id FROM client_contact_cases c1_a LEFT JOIN cases c2_a ON (c1_a.case_id = c2_a.case_id) 
     WHERE c1_a.client_id = c1.client_id AND c2_a.case_created_date < c2.case_created_date
     ) 
ORDER BY Case_ID ASC
```

EXPLAIN Result:

```
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'c3', 'ALL', 'PRIMARY', NULL, NULL, NULL, '29340', 'Using where; Using     temporary; Using filesort'
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'c1', 'ref',     'client_has_cases_FKIndex1,client_contact_has_cases_FKIndex2',     'client_has_cases_FKIndex1', '4', 'prod1_cases_clients.c3.client_contact_id', '1', 'Using index'
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'c2', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'prod1_cases_clients.c1.case_id',     '1', 'Using where'
'2', 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'c1_a', 'index', 'client_contact_has_cases_FKIndex2', 'client_contact_has_cases_FKIndex2', '4', NULL, '33682', 'Using where; Using index'
'2', 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'c2_a', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'prod1_cases_clients.c1_a.case_id', '1', 'Using where'
```

Here is the EXPLAIN result if I change the subquery to:

```
...SELECT c1_a.case_id FROM client_contact_cases c1_a 
     WHERE c1_a.client_id = c1.client_id AND c1_a.case_id < c2.case_id
```

EXPLAIN:

```
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'c3', 'ALL', 'PRIMARY', NULL, NULL, NULL, '29340', 'Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort'
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'c1', 'ref', 'client_contact_has_cases_FKIndex1,client_contact_has_cases_FKIndex2', 'client_contact_has_cases_FKIndex1', '4', 'prod1_cases_clients.c3.client_contact_id', '1', 'Using index'
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'c2', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'prod1_cases_clients.c1.case_id',     '1', 'Using where'
'2', 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'c1_a', 'ALL', 'client_contact_has_cases_FKIndex2', NULL, NULL, NULL, '33682', 'Range checked for each record (index map: 0x4)'
```

What is up with the 'Range checked for each record (index map: 0x4)'? There should be an index on everything. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, I figured out a subquery to use that's not dependent! I am instead checking for case_ids that are in a list of clients' 1st cases in the subquery. Now it runs in less than half a second. I would love to put something in the WHERE clause here to whittle it down more. I can't put in the date range as it would prevent the query from checking for previous cases and give me slightly more results than it should, but I did later add in a c3_a.refer_by = 'Referring Partner #1'.

The subquery is now:

```
AND c2.case_id IN (
    SELECT MIN(c2_a.case_id)  
    FROM client_contact_cases c1_a LEFT JOIN cases c2_a ON (c1_a.case_id = c2_a.case_id) 
    GROUP BY c1_a.client_id
 )
```